# Sencha GXT Grid widget ListStore.getAll() only returns partial data

Tags: java, debugging, grid, gxt

When I try to pull all the values of my grid's list store, instead of giving me all of the data in the store it only presents me with the data in the current view of the user.

Example:

I have a grid that looks something like this

1: Apple

2: Boy

3: dog

4: juice

5: slide

6: java

7: python

8: php

9: keyboard

10: rake

However, when looking at the grid in real-time, only 5 of them are available in the current window, while the rest of the 10 are "concealed". Meaning that the user would need to use the grid widget's scroll bar to see the rest of the data. My question is how can I make sure I am interacting with the entire list store and not just portions of it?

Comment: See whether `ListStore.size()` returns the right count. Also try calling `ListStore.findModelWithKey(String)` to see if that finds concealed records. Otherwise, you must disable paging for the grid if you need access to all the data simultaneously - I believe the GXT grid doesn't keep concealed rows loaded when paging is enabled.

Comment: ListStore.size() returns the incorrect count. How would I disable paging?

Comment: I know there is a regular `ListLoader` instead of a `PagingLoader` (for Grid.setLoader(ListLoader)). If that doesn't help, maybe post your code that creates and configures the Grid. You can also check the [Sencha Javadoc](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/javadoc/index.html) for non-paging versions of classes used to configure a Grid.

Comment: Why is it that the getAll wont return all the elements?

Comment: Because the grid is only loading the current page of elements.

Comment: This is not a paged grid, this is a basic grid with a long scroll: [http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basicgrid]

Answer (score 0):

If you altering the grid data manually, make sure you call the update method of the listStore object, here is some example code:

```
List<Event> listData = listStore.getAll();
for (Event event : listData) {
    event.setText(event.getText()+" altered!");
    listStore.update(event);
}
```

There is one more probability, you are using inline editable grid, if you alter the grid data, make sure you call commit changes method from the list store, here is the example:

```
listStore.commitChanges();
```

I hope this help you. Otherwise, please post your code so I can understand your problem better.

Comment: Basically I am altering the grid data, as you might have suspected from my previous questions and loading up the grid. I am fine with the initial altering, However as soon as the user scrolls up or down the data is changed back to the original data and not the modified.

Comment: How do you altering the grid data? From my experience, at first I do it with a wrong way, something like I get the data object from my listStore and just altering it. The key of altering the grid data is calling the update method at the end of your code, have you called it?